# The derivative of $\langle D\phi_t(V), D\phi_t(W)\rangle $

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

Given a Riemannian manifold $M$, $V,W$ are smooth vector fields, $\phi_t$ is the flow of $X$. Show that $\frac{d}{dt}\langle D\phi_t(V), D\phi_t(W)\rangle = \langle L_X V, W\rangle +\langle V, L_XW\rangle+X\langle V, W\rangle$.

This does not make any sense to me:

$\frac{d}{dt}\langle D\phi_t(V), D\phi_t(W)\rangle = \langle \frac{D}{dt}D\phi_t(V）, W\rangle +\langle V, \frac{D}{dt}D\phi_t(W）\rangle$. Where can the third term possibly come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from where you evaluate the inner product.

$\phi_t\colon M\to M$ is the flow of $X$, so $(d\phi_t)_p\colon T_pM\mapsto T_{\phi_t(p)}M$ and
$$
\langle (d\phi_t)V, (d\phi_t)W\rangle\colon p\mapsto
\langle (d\phi_t)_p V_p, (d\phi_t)_p W_p\rangle_{\phi_t(p)}
$$
so when differentiating with respect to $t$ (at $t=0$), you also need to take account of the change in the point of evaluation $\phi_t(p)$.

Comment: That makes sense! How would you prove the identity though. I am also very confused as to how I should compute $\langle \frac{D}{dt} D\phi_t(V), W \rangle$. I remembered being told that the lie derivative and derivative along a curve are different but this seems not to be the case here.

Comment: Differentiating the flow at $t=0$ gives you the Lie derivative wrt $X$.